# Running tests with Spring Data Mongodb auditing enabled

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I a trying to find way to have the auditing features of spring-data-mongodb when performing some tests.

My tests are basically starting an embedded mongo, and wiring my db component with a MongoTemplate.

```
public class MyRepoImpl implements MyRepoCustom {
    @Autowired
    public MyRepoImpl(MongoOperations operations) {
        /* init stuff here */
    }
    @Override
    public MyModel runComplexQuery() { /* do stuff here, such as saving data */ }
}
```

When I am performing the tests, I can't find a way to set up the MongoTemplate in such a way that the auditing takes place (at least for some specific tests), without loading the whole Spring application.

Is there a way to set the MongoTemplate/MongoOperations in order to have the auditing feature running ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring Boot you can use the `@DataMongoTest` annotation to only configure MongoDB starter.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@Import(ExtraMongoConfiguration.class) // if you need some @Configuration to be imported
public class SomeRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the solution when switching from spring boot 1.3 to 1.5 :)